# nullPoint Exception on getResources()

Tags: java, android

i' m getting nullPoint exception on `getResources()` method. I'm starting the activity below from an another class with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FooActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and from the `activity` called, i have set the context that is used by a not-Activity class.

```
class FooActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    [...]
    Display display  = new Display(...);
    display.setContext(this.getApplicationContext());
  }
}
```

class that use the `getResources()` method:

```
class Display{
   private static Context context;

   public Display(...){ } 

   public void doSomething(){
     **** NullPoint exception Row ****
    Bitmap bitmpa = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.custom_marker);
   }

   public void setContext(Context context) {
     if (context == null)
      this.context = context;
    }
}
```

**my Logcat:**

```
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at com.graphic.core.Display.doSomething(Display.java:43)
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-24 20:18:46.656: E/AndroidRuntime(10526):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***is the context  not set properly , that cause the nullPoint?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the initialisation of the context to the Constructor like this :

```
public Display(Context context){ 
       this.context = context;
   }
```

Comment: if you see there is a setMethod on my Display class.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku it's preffered to make the initialisation of the context in the constructor , in your case , can you tell us when you have called the doSomthing() method , because it depends on the call position if it's before or after the setting of the context

Comment: what you said is all right, but the method is called after the context's setting, that's is weird.

Comment: and in your case your context is not initialised to null , so in all cases it will not be set

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to initialize the context in the constructor of the Display class. By doing so, you ensure that the context is properly set when the Display object is created, avoiding the null pointer exception when calling getResources() on a null context. Here's an example of how to implement it:

```
    class Display {
    private Context context;

    public Display(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.custom_marker);
        // Rest of the code...
    }
}
```

Make sure to update the constructor of the Display class to accept a Context parameter and assign it to the context field. This way, the context will be available when calling getResources() in the doSomething() method.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).